# creating parameterized graphs in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a table with below data
Month   Savings Insurance
Jan-10  1000    8978
Feb-10  3432    6756
Mar-10  55  898
Apr-10  56767   6566
May-10  675 545
Jun-10  6456    9898
Jul-10  67435   4564
Aug-10  876 9878
Sep-10  565 3454

I need to create a chart, with Months against Deduction(Savings and Insurance). Need to pass 3 parameters. 
1. From Month
2. To Month
3. Deductions(should be either Savings or Insurance)

Please advise.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the x-axis min and max values to your @frommonth and @tomonth parameter values.  Then use an expression to set the value in your chart to savings or insurance. You can do something like

```
=iif(@deductions = "Insurance",Fields!Insurance.Value, Fields!Savings.Value)
```